# Prove $\|g(x)\|<M$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $g:A \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a function with $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$. Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}g(x)=q \implies$ there exists a $\delta>0$ and a $M>0$ such that $\|g(x)\|<M$ whenever $\|x-a\|<\delta$.

**My attempt:**

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Since we are given that $g(x) \to q$, we know $\exists \delta >0$ such that $|g(x)-q|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<||x-a||<\delta$.

Consider $$\|g(x)\|= \|(g(x)-q)+q\| \leq \|g(x)-q\|+ \|q\| \leq |g(x) -q|+|q|< \epsilon + |q|$$

Choose $M = \epsilon + |q|$

We then have that $\|g(x)\|< M$ whenever $\|x-a\|<\delta$.

Is this correct?

Comment: You should use \| instead of || for norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon = 1\Rightarrow \exists \delta > 0: \|x-a\|< \delta \Rightarrow \|g(x)-q\| < 1\Rightarrow \|g(x)\|-\|q\| < ||g(x)-q|| < 1 \Rightarrow \|g(x)\| < 1+\|q\| = M$.

Comment: \| formats better than || for norms